# Unable to successfully loop through a redux store after a dispatch function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to add product items to my redux store called `cart`. After adding an item I then compare both stores `product(redux store)` and `cart(redux store)` to check if the product has the same `itemCode(item code`. if they do I would like to Hide the add button and show the remove button. Unfortunately I'm getting different results, please look at the picture below for reference:

```
interface IProps {
  items: ItemInterface[];
  documentItems: ItemInterface[];
  onAddItem: any;
}

const ItemFlatList2: FC<Partial<IProps>> = ({
  items,
  documentItems,
  onAddItem,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <ul>
        {items!.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div className={styles.itemContainer}>
              <div key={item.itemCode}>
                <li>{item.itemCode}</li>
                <li>{item.itemDescription}</li>
                {documentItems!.length === 0 ? (
                  <AddButton
                    title={"ADD"}
                    onClick={() =>
                      onAddItem(
                        item.itemCode,
                        item.itemDescription,
                        item.itemSellingPrice
                      )
                    }
                  />
                ) : (
                  documentItems!.map((documentItem) => {
                    if (documentItem.itemCode === item.itemCode) {
                      return <RedButton title={"Remove"} />;
                    }
                    if (documentItem.itemCode !== item.itemCode) {
                      return (
                        <AddButton
                          title={"ADD"}
                          onClick={() =>
                            onAddItem(
                              item.itemCode,
                              item.itemDescription,
                              item.itemSellingPrice
                            )
                          }
                        />
                      );
                    }
                  })
                )}
              </div>

              <div>
                <li>Hello world</li>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemFlatList2;
```

The Cart Store:

```
const initialState: Partial<DocumentDetailsInterface>[] = [
];

const cartStore = createSlice({
  name: "quotation reducer",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    add: {
      reducer: (
        state,
        { payload }: PayloadAction<DocumentDetailsInterface>
      ) => {
        state.push(payload);
      },
      prepare: (item) => ({
        payload: item,
      }),
    },
    edit: (state, { payload }) => {},
    remove: (
      state,
      { payload }: Partial<PayloadAction<DocumentDetailsInterface>>
    ) => {
      const findItem = state.findIndex((item) => payload!.code === item.code);

      if (findItem !== 1) {
        state.splice(findItem, 1);
      }
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {},
});
```

and The Product Store:

```
const initialState: ItemInterface[] = [
  {
    _id: "sdfsd",
    itemType: "Physical Item",
    itemUnitOfMeasure: "Unit",
    itemCode: "PPC10",
    itemDescription: "PPC Cement",
    itemCostPrice: 50,
    itemSellingPrice: 80,
    itemQuantity: 100,
    vatStatus: "Standard rate 15%",

  },
  {
    _id: "qew",
    itemType: "Physical Item",
    itemUnitOfMeasure: "Unit",
    itemCode: "2",
    itemDescription: "Sepako Cement",
    itemCostPrice: 30,
    itemSellingPrice: 60,
    itemQuantity: 100,
    vatStatus: "Standard rate 15%",

  },
  {
    _id: "sdfsd",
    itemType: "Physical Item",
    itemUnitOfMeasure: "Unit",
    itemCode: "1",
    itemDescription: "PPC Cement",
    itemCostPrice: 50,
    itemSellingPrice: 80,
    itemQuantity: 100,
    vatStatus: "Standard rate 15%",

  },
];

const itemSlice = createSlice({
  name: "item reducer",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {},
});
```

[image: Reference Picture]

Comment: Put your code of reducer.

Comment: can you add to code sandbox?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have wrong logic in you render method. You displayed "Add" button when there are no items in `documentItems` and the if any items inside you keep adding "Add" buttons if they are not equal to `itemCode`. So basically you have 2 loops. First is render items, and second one is to render buttons for each item. But you can use one loop to render items and have logic to check if that item is already in the `documentItems` array - if not then display "Add" button, else "Remove" button.

```
return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <ul>
          {items!.map(item => {
            return (
              <div className={styles.itemContainer} key={item.itemCode}>
                <div key={item.itemCode}>
                  <li>{item.itemCode}</li>
                  <li>{item.itemDescription}</li>
                  {documentItems!.findIndex(
                    documentItem => documentItem.itemCode === item.itemCode,
                  ) === -1 ? (
                    <AddButton
                      title={'ADD'}
                      onClick={() =>
                        onAddItem(
                          item.itemCode,
                          item.itemDescription,
                          item.itemSellingPrice,
                        )
                      }
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <RedButton title={"Remove"} />
                  )}
                </div>

                <div>
                  <li>Hello world</li>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide a unique key to button. Write the statemen when you are changing the state

```js
<AddButton
  title={"ADD"}
  key={item.itemCode}
  onClick={() =>
    onAddItem(
      item.itemCode,
      item.itemDescription,
      item.itemSellingPrice
    )
  }
/>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work after mapping a key to each button

Answer (score 0):

You used `map` function to check if item exists in the documentItems. I think changing it to `some` function will work out.

```
documentItems!.some((documentItem) => {
    return documentItem.itemCode === item.itemCode
    }
) ? (<RedButton title={"Remove"} />): (
    <AddButton
        title={"ADD"}
        onClick={() =>
        onAddItem(
            item.itemCode,
            item.itemDescription,
            item.itemSellingPrice
        )
        }
    />
);
```